# Play sendo executado após o Pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, estou tentando executar um mp3 e estou com um problema, quando clico no botão pause ele executa o comando, porem logo em seguida ele executa o Play, o que pode ser?

PLAYMUSICA.PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list span').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "play.php",
        data: { file: $(this).attr('id') }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#play').html(msg);
    });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="play"></div>
<div id="list">
  <span id="1"><img src='images/btn-play-enable.png' title='Ouvir' alt='Play'></span> Quero Celebrar<br />
</div>
```

PLAY.PHP

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#play').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('player').play();
        alert('play');
    });

    $('#pause').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('player').pause();
        alert('pause');
    });

    $('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
        $('#seekbar').attr("value", this.currentTime / this.duration);
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<?php
    include("conexao.php");

    mysqli_select_db($conn, "mg") or die("<b>Erro ". mysqli_errno() . "</b> - " . mysqli_error());

    $sql1 = "SELECT musica_uid, nm_musica FROM tbl_musica WHERE id_musica = '".intval($_GET['file'])."'"; 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); 

    while($consulta1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {; 
        $uid = $consulta1['musica_uid'];
        $musica = $consulta1['nm_musica'];
    }
?>

<audio id="player" autoplay preload="none"> 
    <source src="get-musica.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>" type="audio/mp3"> 
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div>
    <?php echo $musica; ?><br>
    <button id="play"> > </button>
    <button id="pause">||</button>
    <progress id="seekbar" value="0" max="1" style="width:200px;"></progress><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: experimente colocar nos button. type="button"

Comment: Poderia postar como está chamando o arquivo `.mp3`? Seu código [está funcionando aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/bzhz8n6p/)

Comment: Aonde está o Elemento com ID="player" no seu HTML?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ver se fica mais claro a minha dúvida... Vlw

Comment: Já experimentaste verificar o estado antes de aplicar a acção ?

Comment: @Edilson não! Como faria isso?

Comment: Assim? if (player.paused) {....

Comment: `var vid = $('#play'); vid.on('click', function(){ if(vid.paused){ vid.play(); } else { vid.pause(); } })` - Exeperimenta isto.